# Find Magento 2 controller and template for a given URL

Tags: magento, magento2

I know how the magento 2 routing is working, but I can't find this one.

My url is `http://mywebsite/confirmation-envoi`

So I was looking for an `index_index_confirmation-envoi.xml` or may be a `Controller/Index/Index/ConfirmationEnvoi.php` but still I can't find anything.

more likely, I was expecting a `frontName ="confirmation-envoi"` inside a `routes.xml` but still nothing is appearing.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: I think the right Controller path could be `Vendor/Module/Controller/Index/Index.php` as well.

Comment: @L.Gerhardt Actually I finally find out the mystery, this page was one of the cms page created from inside the admin :)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I completely forgot about cms blocks and pages.